# How to solve $4\sin x\cos x+2\sqrt3\sin x-2\cos x-\sqrt3=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I solve the trigonometric equation $$4\sin x\cos x+2\sqrt3\sin x-2\cos x-\sqrt3=0$$

I used to replace $\sin x$ by $\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}$ but doesn't work very well ;°

I just want a hint kiss:°

Comment: Is this a homework problem ? What have you tried? In german they say " Nie versagen, Wolfram fragen "..... they don't actually say that.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Note that $$4\sin x\cos x+2\sqrt3\sin x-2\cos x-\sqrt3=0$$ is equivalent to $$\left(2\sin x-1\right)\left(2\cos x+\sqrt3\right)=0.$$ Can you take it from here?

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: Best wishes and kisses... the person said he wanted a kiss.

Comment: @PandaBear and of course lot of smiles $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$